# google spreadsheet select a column with substring

Tags: google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet A, and use import/query command to generate a spreadsheet B, but I wish the selected column display only first 7 characters.

e.g. A has a 1234567890abcdef string, but after apply the select command such as:

```
=query(importrange("docid","sheetname!A:M"),"select Col1")
```

Then wish the output is 1234567 (first 7 characters) but not the whole string 1234567890abcdef.

I wish below command can work but actually not:

```
=query(importrange("docid","sheetname!A:M"),"select left(Col1,7)")
```

Comment: Maybe need to do it with GAS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try wrapping the left function around the query, like:

```
=Arrayformula(Left(query(importrange("docid","sheetname!A:M"),"select Col1"),7))
```